# Architecture/Structure Model and DB - Laravel app

Tags: database, laravel, architecture, model

I have a Record which could be one of 4 types. According to its type it could contain a subrecord of given type. Eg: Record of type "Travel Cost" can contain subrecord of "Gasoline Cost" or "Public Transport Cost" record of type "MealAcco" can contain subrecord of "Meal Cost" or "Accommodation Cost"

How should I represent this in object model and in adjacent DB tables.

I use Laravel framework - if it is important...

Your help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphic relations.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

You need to specify if you need one-to-one or one-to-many.

For example, can each TravelCost have more than Gasoline Cost? Actually, isn't Gasoline Cost more of a Cost type?

You could have a **travelcosts** table (the model would be **Travelcost**)

In that case you would have, among the columns in the table, two columns in your travelcosts table, namely *travelcostable_id* and *travelcostable_type* that link to the corresponding table and id.
For example, *travelcostable_type* would be 'gasoline' while *travelcostable_id* would have 3, being the third record of the Gasoline model table.